# Return array pulled from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to pull all badges associated to a particular user that is logged into my site.  On my index.php page I have,

```
<?php
     include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
     include_once 'includes/functions.php';
     print_r(get_badges($_SESSION['user_id'], $mysqli));
?>
```

My db_connect.php:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
```

and on my functions.php I have,

```
<?php
function get_badges($u, $mysqli){
     $badges[] = array();

     if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM memBadges WHERE ownerId = $u";

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $badges[] = $row["badgeId"]);
        }
    }

$mysqli->close();

return $badges;
}
?>
```

The problem is that the piece in the functions.php page makes my page go blank. When I remove it, the page looks normal.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have an error in your page. Turn on error reporting

Comment: maybe there is a syntax error somewhere, but the message is suppressed by the server?

Comment: How do you use `$mysqli` inside the function `get_badges()` if it is not defined as `global` ?

Comment: This is up on a hosted server and I added " ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL); " and I'm not seeing any error reporting, even in the  error_log.

Comment: @Prokzy, try debuggung. Add `echo 123; exit;` as the first line of the script. Run. See 123? Now move it a line below. Continue until you know what causes the script to die. Tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error in your code . change

```
$badges[] = $row["badgeId"]);
```

to

```
$badges[] = $row["badgeId"];
```

and also change

`$badges[] = array();` to `$badges = array();`

Comment: Wow, I missed that.  Thank you.

Comment: @Prokzy, Sure! Good luck coding